# How do I push these values into a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

str1: 2022-04-30,   2022-04-30, 2022-04-30, 2022-05-01, 2022-05-01, 2022-05-01

str2:10:00,     14:00,      19:00,      10:00,      14:00,      16:00

str3:13:00,     18:00,      21:00,      13:00,      16:00,      18:00

---

I was wondering how the above 3 strings can be made into a multidimensional array,
as I subsequently need to display the unique dates with the corresponding earliest and latest timing, for example:

2022-04-30, 10:00 to 21:00
2022-05-01, 10:00 to 18:00

Tried doing array methods but the outcome doesn't match; does anyone have an idea of how this could be done, I've only managed to get this thus far:

30 Apr 2022 10:00 to 13:00
01 May 2022 10:00 to 13:00

```
$seshDates = explode(",",$dateArr);   //str1
            $seshTimes = explode(",",$timeArr); //str2
            $endseshTimes = explode(",",$etimeArr); //str3
          
          
            $unique=(array_unique($seshDates));
            
            $duplicates = array_diff_assoc($seshDates, $unique);
  

            $unique=(array_unique($seshDates));
            $duplicates = array_diff_assoc($seshDates, $unique);


            foreach($unique as $key=>$newVal){
            $message .= date_format(date_create($newVal),"d M Y");

            $message .= ' '.$seshTimes[$key];
            $message .= ' to ';

            if($etimeArr==''){
                
                $copykey = array_search($newVal, $duplicates);
            if($copykey!=''){
                $time= $seshTimes[$copykey];
                $timestamp = strtotime($time);
                $timestamp_one_hour_later = $timestamp + 14400; 
                $message .= strftime('%H:%M', $timestamp_one_hour_later);
            }else{
              
                $time= $seshTimes[$key];
                $timestamp = strtotime($time);
                $timestamp_one_hour_later = $timestamp + 14400; 
                $message .= strftime('%H:%M', $timestamp_one_hour_later);
                
                
            }
                
            }else{
                
                
                $message .= $endseshTimes[$key];
                
                
                
            }
```

Comment: Can you show with code how you are trying it to work?

Comment: hi suraj, updated with script

Comment: Please include sample of desired output. It's unclear how you expect the dates and times to be combined. Are they related simply by index position?